# How to prove $v(\Omega)=\frac{1}{3}\iint_S\textbf{r} \cdot d\textbf{S} $?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, multivariable-calculus, surface-integrals, multiple-integral

Suppose the boundary of $\Omega\subset \mathbb{R^3}$ is a smooth surface $S$, prove $$v(\Omega)=\frac{1}{3}\iint _S\textbf{r} \cdot d\textbf{S}. $$

When $S$ under the general sphere coordinates $(x,y,z)=(\arcsin\phi \cos\theta ,br\sin\phi \sin\theta, cr\cos\phi)$, $r=r(\phi ,\theta)$, where $ (\phi, \theta)\in D$, then prove $$v(\omega)=\frac{abc}{3}\iint_Dr^3(\phi,\theta)\sin\phi d\phi d\theta.$$

Actually I have considered the case which is the sphere, then it is obvious it is correct. But in general, I think we consider the Gauss's Theorem.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Show your own efforts to get answer(s).

Comment: Yes, this is a direct application of the divergence theorem (Gauss's Theorem)

Comment: What you have written in the title (with scalar $r$ and $dA$) is most definitely different from the flux integral you have written in the question.